# new File("path/tmp.txt") at Jenkins node

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have a very simple pipeline which works on a master. I was reading a line in a tmp.txt which works on Jenkins (master).

```
stage ('Stage 1'){
    node('master') {
        File file1 = new File("env.Workspace/tmp.txt")
        def String my_line = file1.readLines().get(0)
        …
    }
}
```

I’ve have to move the stage to other one node (slave) and it doesn’t work anymore. If there is a tmp.txt in a workspace of master – pipeline reads it. But I want to read the tmp.txt in a workspace of node, not from master!

```
stage ('Stage 1'){
    node('Agent_1') {
        File file1 = new File("env.Workspace/tmp.txt")
        def String my_line = file1.readLines().get(0)
        …
    }
}
```

I've found an info that:

> “File always implies a file path on the current computer”.

What does it mean? It must be possible to read a file from node..

Can anybody help there?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use native Groovy/Java IO functions, but use [pipeline steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/) instead. The reason for this is that the pipeline code itself is always executed on the master!

The correct (pseudo) code, using the [`readFile`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace) step, would be like:

```
stage ('Stage 1'){
    node('Agent_1') {
        def String my_line = readFile("tmp.txt")
        …
    }
}
```